# Setting row order in R using levels

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Please don't mark this as duplicate as I will take this question down once I find out what's wrong. I have used **Levels()** with a very high degree of success and today it refuses to work come what may. Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have two data frames with an identical column. I am using the simple **merge()** function as follows:

```
mergedData<-merge(df1, df2, by='Index')
```

Now, I want to reorder the 'Index' column i.e. reorder the rows in the 'mergedData' file to match the order in either of the original dataframes. This is the command I am using to achieve the reordering:

```
mergedData$Index<-factor(mergedData$Index,
levels=c("ND","TC","PR","W","MI"))
```

When I test the levels after running the above command it shows the desired order however when I export the table it retains the original order. I am extremely confused as to why this isn't working. I have other scripts wherein I've used this approach of setting the desired order and it is working perfectly fine except in this instance.

Any help/suggestions/advise would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached data from the two dataframes for you all to play around with:

df1

```
structure(list(Index = structure(1:5, .Label = c("ND", "TC", 
"PR", "W", "MI"), class = "factor"), `CP` = c(0.7102, 
0.059, -0.0469, 1.0137, 0.6116), FA1 = c(0.5218, 0.0249, -0.0532, 
0.9561, 1.1676), FA2 = c(0.5625, 0.0397, -0.0712, 0.9636, 0.9569
), FA3 = c(0.5934, 0.0332, -0.0442, 0.9873, 0.8929)), .Names = c("Index", 
"CP", "FA1", "FA2", "FA3"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

df2

```
structure(list(Index = structure(1:5, .Label = c("ND", "TC", 
"PR", "W", "MI"), class = "factor"), `CP SD` = c(0.0241, 
0.0184, 0.0021, 0.0114, 0.0947), `FA1 SD` = c(0.1891, 0.0171, 
0.0104, 0.0559, 0.5321), `FA2 SD` = c(0.1273, 0.0243, 0.0173, 
0.0565, 0.3292), `FA3 SD` = c(0.0518, 0.0094, 0.0078, 0.0195, 
0.1581)), .Names = c("Index", "CP SD", "FA1 SD", "FA2 SD", 
"FA3 SD"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`levels` only controls the order of the factor levels (how it will be displayed by `levels(x)`, in `table`, etc.), not the order of the rows in a data.frame. To order a data frame, use this:

```
mergedData <- mergedData[order(mergedData$Index),]
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
mergedData <- arrange(mergedData,Index)
```

Comment: Thanks @Scoa. It works okay. I was ignorant all this while I suppose. Cheers.